# I can't find my addons path (odoo 8)

Tags: odoo, odoo-8

I developed a new module and I want to add it to my `odoo` on the server but when I access to my files I don't find addons file in order to put the module. I tried a lot of paths but I didn't find it even my opt file is empty any suggestions or ideas please ? `odoo` is installed on `ubuntu 14.0`
I used to find my `addons` on `opt/odoo/odoo`

This code I added it just to be able to publish my question because I could not publish it without code

```
<record id="view_order_product_graph" model="ir.ui.view">
   <field name="name">sale.report.graph</field>
   <field name="model">sale.report</field>
   <field name="arch" type="xml">
        <graph string="Sales Analysis" type="pivot" stacked="True">
            <field name="section_id" type="row"/>
            <field name="date" interval="month" type="col"/>
            <field name="price_total" type="measure"/>
         </graph>
    </field>
</record>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put your modules on the system where ever you want. What you have to know is, where to find the server config file. If you've installed Odoo by package installer, it should be in `/etc/odoo/*.conf`.

In this file you can add paths to the line `addons_path=...`. Save the config and restart the Odoo instance. Reload the Modules in Odoo and you will find the custom modules.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Python` interpreter:

```
>>> import openerp
>>> openerp.addons.__path__
['/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/addons']
>>>
```

Comment: @ilham Anytime.